# Super Town, USA, Superman Comic

Tags: dc, superman, parallel-universe

Once upon a time I read a comic from the 1990s, I think, that had Superman waking up in a little town and having a look around. He'd been chasing Lex Luthor's thugs into another dimension. In this town, everyone wore capes, including the mailman. It was very Twilight Zone. Everyone had super powers.

There, he goes to a Mom & Pop diner, just pretending to be a new guy in town. Nobody knew him as Superman or anybody important, and one of the ladies commented on how nice his cape was, and how hard it was to get grass stains out of her kid's. Or something like that. Superman has a steak.

Then Lex Luthor's thugs, dressed up like superpowered commandos, with laser weapons of course, appear, and everyone freaks out about the "normals." Superman fights them, of course, captures them, and sends them home.

It's really weird. Everyone was afraid of normals even though they could have easily trounced the commandos in so many different ways. By the town's standards Superman was just a normal guy. And I think the people there had gone to this dimension intentionally to get away from the normals, like in that Halloweentown movie.

I think the comic was part of a series of comics. At least two, because the beginning of the adventure wasn't in the one I read.

Comment: The name Super Town was used to describe the New Gods' city on New Genesis, and Superman spent several issues of Jimmy Olsen trying to get there.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, particular, comic book. The one I talk about does not have Jimmy in it at all. It happens in america in an alternative universe town, not another planet.